# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react-dom/client". --- Using Express server and TypeScript client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, express

**Full Error:**

Seeing this error client-side, in the browser console, trying to import the react modules from my server's node_modules folder.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react-dom/client". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

---

Edit:
I am seeing this error in the client/ in the browser console, trying to import a module from my node_modules folder on the server, using a non-relative path. Most React example code I've seen uses this non-relative reference, so I don't understand why it doesn't work for me since I thought React is intended to run on the client for client-side rendering, so I assume this is a common use case.

---

I'm making my first website to learn various web technologies and now I'm learning React. I want to add React to my existing project by making a few components to use in my pages. That's why I haven't used "Create React App" as I want to add it in to my existing setup.

I have:

- An Express server written in JavaScript/ NodeJS
- Client side code is written in TypeScript
- I'm using Pug to generate HTML on the server, but that is probably not relevant.
- I'm using npm for managing react, express, etc packages
- I am not using anything for bundling

I've seen a lot of similar questions but can't find solutions that help me. People seem to be using webpack or talk about bundling which is something I've ignored so far as I haven't needed it so far.

I have made a simple page in my project mimicking my setup to simplify investigating - a static HTML file, which includes a .ts file as a module, which imports a .tsx file. I still get the error here.

**Folder structure:**

```
BudgetV1
  |- node_modules
  | |- @types
  | | |- react
  | | |- react-dom
  | |- react  
  | |- react-dom
  |
  |- public
  | |- reactPractice.html
  |
  |- scripts
  | |- practicingReact.ts
  | |- helpInsertReact.tsx
  |
  |- app.js
  |- package.json
  |- tsconfig.json
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "budgetv1pug",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "devstart": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "serverstart": "SET DEBUG=budgetv1pug:* & npm run devstart"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^3.2.4",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.2",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.6.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015",
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./public/out",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "watch": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "include": ["./scripts/*"]
}
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

// Set up mongoose connection
.....

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'))); // Tried adding this but didn't help.

app.use('/', catalogRouter)

// ...
// More unrelated app.use() setup calls
// ...

module.exports = app;
```

**reactPractice.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    <script src="./out/practicingReact.js" type="module"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**practicingReact.ts**

```
import insertReact from "./reactComponents/helpInsertReact.js";

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
    console.log("DOMContentLoaded");
    insertReact();
});
```

**helpInsertReact.tsx**

```
import React, { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client"; // Problem line

export default function insertReact() {
    console.log("insertReact");
    let rootDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("root")!;
    const root = createRoot(rootDiv);
}
```

And finally in the browser dev tools Console, the error on page load:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react-dom/client". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

in reactPractice.html:1

Note that if I add a line in helpInsertReact.tsx that uses something from "react" I get a similar error for 'module specifier "react"'.

I can see the GET request for helpInsertReact.js come into my server, but I can't see the file in the Sources tab of browser dev tools. I'm guessing it doesn't even begin running because of the 'failed to resolve...' error

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react-dom/client". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"." typically occurs when there is an issue with importing a module in a JavaScript application.

This error message specifically suggests that the module specifier "react-dom/client" cannot be resolved because it does not start with "/", "./", or "../".

To fix this error, you should update the module specifier to start with one of these characters. For example, if you are trying to import a module called "client" that is located in the same directory as your current file, you would use "./client" as the module specifier. If "client" is located in a parent directory, you would use "../client".

If you are still having issues after updating the module specifier, you may want to check that the module you are trying to import is actually installed and available in your project's dependencies. You can do this by checking your package.json file or running the command "npm ls" in your project's directory.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried your suggestion but get issues since I am using typescript.

import { createRoot } from "../node_modules/react-dom/client";
Error on server:
Could not find a declaration file for module '../node_modules/react-dom/client'. 'c:/Budget V1/node_modules/react-dom/client.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7016)

Comment: The typescript types information (.d.ts files) are in node_modules/@types/react-dom so if I update the import to that I get an error in the browser

import { createRoot } from "../node_modules/@types/react-dom/client";

GET http://localhost:8000/node_modules/@types/react-dom/client net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

So I don't know how I can import it using a relative reference. There are other reasons I was trying to use that type of reference - I'll add clarification in my question.

Comment: Sorry character limit got me! Also pressing enter sent the comment

Comment: is it installed in the modules? its in the httpd.conf files. search up the module name and add it to the list of LoadModule's.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what that means, where do I find the httpd.conf files? Is it in the server set up somewhere?

Comment: what hosting program (such as apache) do you use? if you use xampp, depending if ur server is on linux or windows, it will be in either /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf and for windows im pretty sure its C:\xampp\apache\httpd.conf though it could be wrong. if ur in the xampp control panel and see the apache service, theres a config button, click that and select httpd.conf. in the httpd.conf hit ctrl + f to find and search for react-dom or something like that

Comment: I'm not using apache, I'm using Express for the server and then I run it locally using npm in the commandline. I think the setup for my server is quite different to apache and maybe I need to use a bundling tool like webpack to send all the react dependencies, which I might set up in the future. For now I have decided to use a script tag in my html with a URL to "https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" and the same for react-dom. And that works fine as a workaround for now.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. i forgot you were using express server. I dont know too much about express server, so if you still have any problems after this, then you should probably try and find someone else for it.

Comment: good that you found a workaround though, hope it works for a little while

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think most likely I need to use something like Webpack to do dependency bundling but I'll save that for another day!